# Get data after api call in ngrx effect

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I'm using Ngrx Effect to get data from API, then I would get that data in my component.

**In component**

```
schedules$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectSchedulings));
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(new GetSchedules());
}
```

In actions I have created two types

```
export class GetSchedules implements Action {
  public readonly type = ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDate;
}
export class GetSchedulesSuccess implements Action {
  public readonly type = ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess;
  constructor(public payload: ISchedules[]) {}
}

export type SchedulesAction = GetSchedules | GetSchedulesSuccess;
```

Then In my effects

```
export class SchedulingsEffects {
  loadSchedulings$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDate),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.apiCallsService.getSchedulings().pipe(
          map(movies => ({ type: ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess, payload: movies })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private apiCallsService: ApiCallsService) {}
}
```

I have initialized my store in state

```
import { ISchedules } from '../../shared/interfaces/scheduling.interface';
export interface ISchedulesState {
  schedulings: ISchedules;
}

    export const initialSchedulingState: ISchedulesState = {
      schedulings: {
        status: '',
        data: [
          {
          ..... Init values....
          }
        ]
      }
    };
```

And reducers

```
export const SchedulingReducers = (
  state = initialSchedulingState,
  action: SchedulesAction
): ISchedulesState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDate: {
      return {
        ...state
      };
    }
    case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess: {
      return {
        ...state
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

When I run my app , I only get Init values. I see in store dev tools that the api is triggered and data is stored, but why `schedules$` don't get update ?

Comment: But in your `reducer` for `GetSchedulesByDateSuccess` action there is no payload, that you want to add to the state, you're returning just `state`

Comment: right , I have added payload to , now it's working thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess: {
      return {
        ...state
      };
    }
```

Here, you're just returning a cope of the state.
What you should do is using the `action` payload to update the state (I don't exactly know how your state is structured, but this gives an idea):

```
 case ESchedulesActions.GetSchedulesByDateSuccess: {
      return {
        ...state,
        schedulings: action.payload
      };
    }
```